# Contact header in 4xx responses?

Tags: sip

The Statement in RFC 3261 about presence of Contact Header in 4xx responses are contradictory. Does anyone have any explanation for the same?

As per RFC 3261 - 13.2.2.3 -

> A single non-**2xx** final response may be received for the **INVITE**.  **4xx**, **5xx** and **6xx** responses may contain a **Contact** header field value indicating the location where additional information about the error can be found.  Subsequent final responses (which would only arrive under error conditions) MUST be ignored.

However, in RFC 3261 Section 20.1

> ```
>  Contact                 R            o   -   -   m   o   o
>  Contact                1xx           -   -   -   o   -   -
>  Contact                2xx           -   -   -   m   o   o
>  Contact                3xx      d    -   o   -   o   o   o
>  Contact                485           -   o   -   o   o   o
> ```

Also the Book "SIP: understanding the Session Initiation Protocol" By Alan B. Johnston Page 77 says that

> A user agent sending a **REGISTER** request may receive a **3xx** redirection or **4xx** failure response containing a **Contact** header of the location to which registrations should be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section 13.2.2.3 should probably read "an Error-Info header field value indicating the location where additional information about the error can be found".

This question was resolved on the SIP Implementers group:
http://www.mail-archive.com/sip-implementors@cs.columbia.edu/msg10493.html

Comment: That's what I thoougt after reading about "Error-Info" header.

A UAC MAY treat a SIP or SIPS URI in an Error-Info header field as if it were a Contact in a redirect and generate a new INVITE, resulting in a recorded announcement session being established.  A non-SIP URI MAY be rendered to the user.